# Python: (Probably very simple) problem with basic function: How do I make this set of functions work?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm very new to Python and am trying to write this set of functions as a "Happy Test" where you enter your name and it will tell you "You tested happy" but if your name is Anthony (my friend's name), it will say 'You tested sad". 
Every time I try to run it (in Eclipse, using Pydev, grammar version 3.8 and interpreter Python 3.8), it  immediately shows a terminated message at the top above the console and nothing is shown in the console. I have looked through it and I'm just not sure how to properly achieve this.

```
def HappyTest(n):
    n = input('What is your name?')
    def message1():
        return 'You tested sad'
    def message2():
        return 'You tested happy'
    the_bad_news = n+message1()
    the_good_news = n+message2()
    if str(n) == 'Anthony':
        return the_good_news
    else:
        return the_bad_news
```

Comment: You’re never *calling* `HappyTest`…‽

Answer (score 0):

You just defined `HappyTest` so you should call your function. the `n` argument is useless so remove it : 
Try  this :

```
def HappyTest():
    n = input('What is your name?')
    def message1():
        return 'You tested sad'
    def message2():
        return 'You tested happy'
    the_bad_news = n+message1()
    the_good_news = n+message2()
    if str(n) == 'Anthony':
        return the_good_news
    else:
        return the_bad_news
HappyTest()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code in a better way:

```
def HappyTest():
n = input('What is your name?')
if str(n) == 'Anthony':
    print(str(n)+' You tested positive happy')
else:

    print(str(n)+' You tested sad')
```